# is it possible to run R as a daemon

Tags: r, daemon

I have a script in R that is frequently called during the day (by other scripts). I call R in a terminal using

```
Rscript code.R
```

I notice it takes a lot of time to load packages and set up R.

Is it possible to run R as a background service which I hit using a port or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, look into [RServe](https://rforge.net/Rserve/) which has been available for over a dozen years for this reason.  There are a couple of fairly high profile applications too.

Comment: +1. It’s worth noting that RServe is of course not necessary — one can simply use Rscript/littler/whatever to execute a normal R scrip that sets up its own TCP/IP listener.

Comment: True -- and things like [rzmq](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rzmq) even make to possible to 'serve' easily.  [RServe](https://rforge.net/Rserve/) is still more general in offering the full REPL.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Would it be possible to load up trained models (.RDA) and and libraries also?

Comment: Yes, as there are essentially no limits to what R scripts you can load at startup of the session started by Rserve.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this add-in for Rstudio, it is not a port like solution but maybe it can help you https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR