# How to speed up the package/library loading time in R?

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, rscript, install.packages

I have a `run_stat.r` script that can run in command line such as `Rscript anova.r` on my ubuntu server:

```
#load package   
library(ez)  
#run code....
```

The problem is that the loading time of `ez` package would take 2~3 seconds.

Can R preload the package one time, so that it doesn't need to re-load the same package every time I run the script? Any suggestions to speed up the loading time of the package?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically may help you.

Comment: Thanks. But I've already seen this post. It just "auto-load" the package when R start. What I want is something like the "shared session". I'm not sure if R support something like this?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569997/is-it-possible-to-run-r-as-a-daemon