# How to profile the loading of an R package

Tags: r, profiling, r-package

I have written this R package that takes ages (> 10s, sometimes up to 20-30s!) to load.

Every time the package loads, such as when building the package at the step `"** testing if installed package can be loaded"`, or directly calling `library("my.package")`, nothing happens for 20s.

This makes everything painfully slow during development: building documentation, building the package, running R check...

Of course I have my suspicions (looking at you, dodgy dependency), but I need to gather evidence before axing it.

Is there a way to profile the loading of the package, in order to identify the cause? Or more generally, how can I figure out what is happening under the hood?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the times during build? Identify what takes a lot of time and fix?

Comment: The slow step when building documentation is the loading (`"Loading my.package..."`). The slow step when building the package is "`** testing if installed package can be loaded`". Simply directly calling `library("my.package")` takes 10-20s. It really is the loading that seems to be slow.

Comment: Do you have anything that is done on load(attach?) or call some other packages at that step?

Comment: @NelsonGon Not that I am aware of. My code in `/R` only defines functions and some small hard-coded vectors. I also have a small dataset in an `.rda` file in `/data`. I am pretty certain this comes from one of the dependencies doing things on attach, but I have over 30 so trial-and-error would be annoying (it's not just removing the package in DESCRIPTION but editing the NAMESPACE or removing the `@importFrom`, etc). I'd rather profile if possible, given that I can live with the issue for now.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300769/how-to-load-packages-in-r-automatically or this(comment from Dason might be useful) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933479/how-to-speed-up-the-package-library-loading-time-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 Can't think of a more developer way. Maybe someone else knows a solution.

Comment: Maybe you can interactively profile a call to `devtools::load_all`?

Comment: can't you use *profvis* on `loadNamespace()` ?

Comment: @Alexis @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, the profiling shows a total duration of 500-700ms in both cases whereas the actual time is close to 20 seconds. Ignoring that, it does show that most of the time is spent in several `namespaceImportFrom` but it does not say which packages. Any other idea?

Comment: Have you shared your package on Github? If so, can you post the url?

Comment: Unfortunately this particular package is proprietary (developed at work) and we only publish our open-source packages. In any case, I think the question would benefit from a general answer rather than something specific to my package.

Comment: maybe create a R script that calls `library` on those *30* packages and profile this R script?

Comment: If the load time is caused by loading some other package on which your package depends, you should be able to see that by first loading that package (`library(dependency)`) and then loading your package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So an issue with using the detach method from @davide-lorino is that if there are entangled `depends` or `imports`, it will fail, and fail hard.

A better method is to use a `future` backend that loads each of the `import`s in a clean R session, and time how long it takes to load them via `library`.

I implemented this in a package that might be useful to others: https://github.com/rmflight/importedPackageTimings

Answer (score 1):

You can determine which library takes the longest to load by benchmarking a call to load each of the libraries that you are testing.

The key is to make sure that you unload the libraries. If you keep the libraries loaded before re-loading them, the `library()` function will determine that the library has loaded and return out. On a typical benchmark of 100 runs, 1 of them will represent the time it took to load your library, and the remaining 99 will represent the time it took `library()` to figure out that the library is loaded. The result (duration) will then be an aggregate of the 100 runs, yielding a very small number and almost no variance between the results, like so:

[image]

When what you really want looks more like:

[image]

Giving us a less surprising result for our efforts.

P.s. the `detach_package()` function is implemented like this:

```
detach_package <- function(pkg, character.only = FALSE)
{
  if(!character.only)
  {
    pkg <- deparse(substitute(pkg))
  }
  search_item <- paste("package", pkg, sep = ":")
  while(search_item %in% search())
  {
    detach(search_item, unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite as automated as I'd want but thanks! I think I'll use your idea but I'll read the dependencies from the DESCRIPTION file and test the packages programmatically. Also, that's assuming slowness issues come from the loading phase of another package... But at some point there must be something else happening. Assuming I go back the chain of slow packages until I find the culprit, how do I diagnose it? I'd welcome another more general answer explaining how to look at what's happening "under the hood".

Comment: Also given the magnitude of the delay observed (~10s) I might as well run a benchmark with `times=1` and not worry about detaching packages.