# Make Dataframe persist for multiple requests

Tags: r, data-science

I have a large, sparse matrix saved in a RData file. The script to access this matrix will be kicked off from a console call to RScript. It is both time and resource intensive to load this matrix on every call from the script. Is there a way to hold a matrix in memory so that multiple calls from the console can use the matrix without having to load it as an object every single time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569997/is-it-possible-to-run-r-as-a-daemon

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'bigmatrix' package. Basically you create a matrix with a call to 'big.matrix()', then obtain a hook to that matrix through a call to 'describe()'. The content of the hook can then be used to attach the already loaded matrix into another process using 'attach.big.matrix()'.

**Edit:** an example:

Start 2 R sessions, 1 & 2

#### on Session 1:

```
require(bigmemory)
system.time(M <- matrix(rnorm(1e8), 1e4)) # ~9"
format(object.size(M), "Mb") # ~762Mb
system.time(M <- as.big.matrix(M)) # ~ 3"

hook = describe(M)
saveRDS(hook, "shared-matrix-hook.rds")
M[1:3,1:3]
```

#### on Session 2

```
require(bigmemory)
system.time(hook <- readRDS("shared-matrix-hook.rds")) # 0.001"

system.time(Mshared <- attach.big.matrix(hook)) # 0.002"

Mshared[1:3,1:3] # shows the same as session 1 did
Mshared[2,2] = 0 # check on session 1 that this change is present there
```

Comment: Interesting approach. But how does it hold the "state" of the matrix in a quick-to-load manner from one script request to another?

Comment: one way for holding the "state" is to save the hook (the result from 'describe()') to a file, that will be read when there is another call.

Answer (score 0):

Should not the problem of sharing large data fundamentally introduce an architecture that can use data sharing like in-memory DB?